# R3Corda cordapp-example Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils']

Tags: corda

I am trying to install/build/run the r3corda cordapp-example Project. I am following the https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html and https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#downloading-the-example-cordapp but the build fails with above message.
I noticed that the git-clone gradle build tries to install gradle version 5.1.4. whereas the docs state it would only work with version 4.10. So I have tried both, manually installing 4.10. but also trying with 5.1.4. Both fail.
Full Message is:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\marc\r3corda\samples\cordapp-example\clients\build.gradle' line: 6
- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils']

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils']
  >   Could not create an instance of type net.corda.plugins.QuasarExtension_Decorated.
  >   No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultPropertyState.convention() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [co.paralleluniverse]

I have also tried using IntelliJ IDE but that did not work either.

Many thanks for your hints and ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you the latest version of the repo? Your issue should be resolve with the new patch on updating gradle wrapper.

If not, can you join the slack channel and ping me directly at slack.corda.net